# Payment Method Error Square Api

Tags: c#, payment-gateway, square, square-connect

I'm trying to integrate Square API with my asp.net C# application and charge a card it give an exception

```
Error calling Charge: {"errors":[{"category":"PAYMENT_METHOD_ERROR","code":"CARD_DECLINED","detail":"Card declined."}]}
```

But when I use Sandbox credential it work fine.

This is the git link for whole code.
https://github.com/square/connect-api-examples/blob/master/connect-examples/v2/csharp_payment/PaymentExample/Default.aspx.cs

Following is my code.

```
private static TransactionsApi _transactionsApi = new TransactionsApi();
        private static string _locationId = "G5CXF7RRQ5**";

[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
        public static string Charge(string nonce)
        {
            string msg = "";
            try
            {
                Configuration.Default.AccessToken = "sq0atp-QXNE1q59un5dzDeDC****";


                string uuid = NewIdempotencyKey();
                Money amount = new Money(100, Money.CurrencyEnum.USD);
                string a = "";

                ChargeRequest body = new ChargeRequest(AmountMoney: amount, IdempotencyKey: uuid, CardNonce: nonce);


                var response = _transactionsApi.Charge(_locationId, body);
                return msg = response.ToJson();
            }
            catch (ApiException e)
            {
                return msg = e.Message;
            }
        }

        public static string NewIdempotencyKey()
        {
            return Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        }
```

Comment: Please put more information and some code you are using in order to easy someone understand your problem and help you.

Comment: This is the git link for whole code.https://github.com/square/connect-api-examples/blob/master/connect-examples/v2/csharp_payment/PaymentExample/Default.aspx.cs

Comment: Now i share my code.....

Answer (score 0):

Square's developer sandbox is more lenient in accepting cards. Try a different card, you are getting the expected error if you card is declined.

Comment: Sir i use more than 10 Card and get same exception                          
 Error calling Charge: {"errors":[{"category":"PAYMENT_METHOD_ERROR","code":"CARD_DECLINED","detail":"Card declined."}]}

Comment: Your code is functioning correctly, perhaps there is something wrong with your account. Could you try making a different account to test from?

Comment: Sir can you please tell me whats wrong with my account setting then i'll fix it. I also think it not a programming error because it working fine for sandbox credential. But i'm unable to track what is the problem with my account.